# How to ssh gcp private vm from local browser website?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-platform, ssh, browser

I am trying to integrate different cloud platforms(aws, gcp…) on my frontend website.

gcp vm has no public ip, only internal ip.

Is there any way that ssh to gcp vm from my html website?

The official doc only has command line tutorial, but it's not what I want.
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-advanced

What kind of gcp api does my backend server need to call, so that allow frontend ssh to gcp VM?

For this requirement, does the gcp api provide similar functionality?

Comment: You will need to use `Connect using Identity-Aware Proxy for TCP forwarding` There is an API for these interfaces. I had to sign an NDA to obtain a copy.

Comment: thx, i try to it(IAP)